# Как вставить getText() в командную строку?

Tags: java

Делаю так

```
Process pr=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=\"name.getText();\"
```

Но вместо введенного значения в TextField получаю `"\"name.getText();"`

Как правильно получить значение из TextField?

Comment: `ssid=\"+name.getText()+\"` не?

Comment: Нет. Так и выводит : +name.getText()+

Comment: значит надо больше кавычек) `ssid=\""+name.getText();+"\"'...в IDE должны увидеть разницу между строкой и выражением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь! 
Решил данную проблему так:

```
" + name.getText() +"
```

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, что вы хотите получить. Если значение должно быть в кавычках, т.е. что-то такое: `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="name"`, то надо сделать так:

```
"netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=\"" + name.getText() + "\""
```

Если же без кавычек, то так:

```
"netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=" + name.getText()
```

В Java, как и во многих других языках, при работе со строками, надо понимать, что `\` означает экранирование символа, т.е. он будет добавлен к строке как есть(либо че как спец. символ, например \n перенос строки), а не восприниматься компилятором, как служебный символ.